# How to show the error message in label instead of display alert using xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

### Here is xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginUser"
             x:Class="LoginUser.MainPage">
  <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Entry x:Name="txtUsername"  Placeholder="Username"></Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="txtPassword" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:ValidationBehavior x:Name="passwordValidator"/>
      </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="##ff77D065" Clicked="Button_Onclick"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### Here is the HandleTextChanged event cs file code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UIKit;

namespace LoginUser
{
    public class ValidationBehavior: Behavior<Entry>
    {
        const string pwRegex = @"^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$";

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

       void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

                bool IsValid = false;
                IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, pwRegex,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
                ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

        }

    }
}
```

For example, I'm giving you the password like App@1234 in password field and If the remove the character string like "A" then the error should occur in label.

Comment: Check my answer which words with your Validator code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a label after password entry:

```
<Label x:Name="errorMessage" TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Italic" />
```

Then in ValidationBehaviour:

```
void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

    bool IsValid = false;
    IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, pwRegex,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;

    // LABEL CODE
    Label errorLabel = ((Entry)sender).FindByName<Label>("errorMessage");
    if (IsValid)
    {
        errorLabel.Text = "Passowrd Invalid or whatever!";
    }
    else
    {
        errorLabel.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I applied your code but the line FindByName is does not exist in the code.

Comment: I applied ((Entry)sender).FindByName<Label>("errorMessage"); then its working fine.
I have set the conditions like one uppercase,one lowercase,one special character for ex: App@1234
If I remove any of the string like "@" then the error should occur so is it possible?
I have set RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not working with Bindings or even MVVM:

What about putting the validation logic into the TextChanged event of your Entry? From there it should be no problem to access a Label by its name and setting the Text-Property of it.

So something like:

```
const string pwRegex = @"^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$";

txtPassword_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool IsValid = false;
    IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, pwRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;

    if(!IsValid)
        lblPasswordValidation.Text = "Password is not valid"; // Put the label you want to set here
    else
        lblPasswordValidation.Text = "";
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should be fine.

Comment: lblPasswordValidation is either Iabel id or anything?

Comment: It is the name of the control. So you have to add a control to your XAML file. This line would do it: `<Label x:Name="lblPasswordValidation" />`